# Not seeing some custom objects and custom fields in Salesforce Workbench

Tags: security, permissions, workbench, visibility

We just promoted a changeset from a Developer Pro sandbox to a Full Copy sandbox. We're not seeing many of the promoted custom objects in workbench for either sandbox. We're not seeing most of the custom fields for the custom objects that we can see, in the Full Copy sandbox. Does anyone have a list of the things I should be checking to understand why these objects / fields are not appearing?

EDIT: The objects that I am not seeing are designed to be Detail objects and have a Master-Detail relationship field. I'm seeing the Master objects in Workbench

EDIT2: I'm seeing the top level master, and its' detail objects, which are themselves masters. I'm not seeing their (third level) detail objects. Does anyone know if there is any limitation to seeing three levels of master detail objects in Workbench?

Comment: api name of object might be different from Name of object.Try searching with api name

Comment: Just to be sure, have you deployed the change set in the full copy sandbox?  After pushing from dev to full you need to deploy it in full.

Comment: Yes it was deployed successfully

Answer (score 3):

for the fields you are unable to see, go to that field in full copy sandbox/ where it is deployed > check "Set field level security" and make sure to check this for your profile/ profile who is not having access in work bench

Comment: +1 - unless you include profile in the change set no field level security will be applied.  So.you need to do this after deploying, or just include profile(s).  As change set is non destructive, only perms for fields being deployed will be included.

Answer (score 0):

The comment made by sfdc above solved part of my issue - at least as far as object visibility. I was simply looking in the wrong place in the Workbench list, expecting the name to match the API name.